# Apply custom mixin (masking) to extjs grid in Ext JS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

We created a custom mixin for load mask, and we need to apply that masking to the locked grid conditionally, how can we set mixin to the grid conditionally?

Comment: As you mentioned *We created a custom mixin for load mask* please provide that code

Comment: i am assigning the mixin like this -- this.self.mixin('samplemask',util.NewMask) , it is working fine in local build, when we do production build Mask is not applying to the grid, if we apply by mixins:['mask'] then it will work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply a mixin conditionally; mixins are, well, mixed into the prototype and apply to all future instances of the class. You obviously can include conditional logic in a mixin, but that's different.

Plugins can be applied per-instance, and may be more useful if, say, you're saying you want *this* grid to have the masking, but don't want it on *that* grid. With a plugin, you apply it as part of initialising the component - you still shouldn't be adding or remove plugins to an already-created instance.

Comment: i am able to apply the mixin conditionally as i mentioned above, in my local its working fine. once i do build and if i point to minified version of app.js then its not working. Why locally its working fine, but not in UAT or QA environment with the minified version of App.js

Comment: Again, you can't actually apply a mixin conditionally. Applying a mixin changes the prototype of your class, and all instances are impacted accordingly. If you want to apply something on a per-instance basis, use a plugin.

This is the case irrespective of why your mixin is or is not being applied.